# DataGrid bindings warnings against null values

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, warnings

I have **warnings** on very simple **DataGrid bindings** due to **value being null sometime**s.

I've tried everything I could find (`FallbackValue` and `TargetNullValue`) but still no luck..

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the
>   binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead.
>   BindingExpression:Path=UpdateUser; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

```
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="HistoryDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HistoricalData}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="UpdateTime" Header="Update time" Binding="{Binding Path=UpdateTime, FallbackValue='', TargetNullValue=''}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="UpdateUser" Header="Update user" Binding="{Binding Path=UpdateUser, FallbackValue='', TargetNullValue=''}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

**UPDATE**

`HistoricalData` is a `List<IHistoricalEntry>`. `IHistoricalEntry` details below (simplified):

```
public interface IHistoricalEntry
{
    DateTime UpdateTime { get; }
    string UpdateUser { get; }
}
```

Any thought?

Comment: What is type of HistoricalData and entry of HistoricalData? I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention, it is List<IHistoricalEntry> where IHistoricalEntry exposes a simple list of properties (mostly String), including the UpdateTime, UpdateUser listed in my extract. Hope it is clearer and thank you really much for your help!

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I have tried many things, but I don't get the Warning. All works good by me. Just for tests - define the setter in interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking further on that. That issue is happening all on my grids and can't figure out why. I've read this could be related to Virtualisation but using EnableColumnVirtualization=False doesn't fix anything